# c# lambda expression convert from vb to c#

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to convert this vb.net code to c#.

```
        If (txtCompanyName.Text.Trim() <> String.Empty) Then
            decals = decals.Where(Function(d As CT_Decal) (From c In db.CT_Companies Where c.CompanyName.Contains(txtCompanyName.Text.Trim()) Select c.CompanyID).ToList.Contains((From t In db.CT_Tanks Where t.CargoTankID = d.TankID Select t.CompanyID).Single.ToString()))
        End If
```

In c# I tried to put the code:

```
        if (txtCompanyName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty)
        {
                    decals = decals.Where(Function(CT_Decal d)(from c in db.CT_Companies 
                                                where c.CompanyName.Contains(txtCompanyName.Text.Trim())
                                                select c.CompanyID).ToList().Contains((from t in db.CT_Tanks                                                                                                    where t.CargoTankID == d.TankID 
                                                select t.CompanyID).Single.ToString()));

        }//end if
```

c# errors:

The name function does not exist and
CT_Decal is a type but is used like a variable.

Does anybody know how to convert this properly?

Comment: Always use `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCompanyName.Text)` instead of `txtCompanyName.Text.Trim() != string.Empty`

Comment: Also, the `ToList()` is redundant and the code shouldn’t compile in VB since `Where` expects a predicate but your lambda is returning a string.

Comment: @jp2code those expressions are not equivalent; they give different results if txtCompanyName.Text contains only whitespace characters.

Comment: @phoog yeh, should be `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` right

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, due to the complexity it's hard to see, but what's actually being returned is the outcome of the Contains method, and that of course returns bool.

Comment: @jessehouwing Indeed, missed one of the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Without access to your DBContext it's hard to give you an exact query, ignoring the inefficiency of the query you're using.

From what we have, I expect the following code gets pretty close to what you want, or at least should get you started:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCompanyName.Text))
        {
            var result = 
                decals.Where(
                    d => (
                        from c in db.CT_Companies 
                            where c.CompanyName.Contains(txtCompanyName.Text.Trim()) 
                            select c.CompanyID
                    ).Contains(
                        (from t in db.CT_Tanks where t.CargoTankID == d.TankID select t.CompanyID).Single()));
```

I expect this will function exactly the same if you've setup your DBContext correctly:

```
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtCompanyName.Text))
        {
            IEnumerable<Decal> result = 
                decals.Where(d => string.Equals(d.Tank.Company.CompanyName, txtCompanyName.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the keyword function within the where clause.

You must write something like this .Where(d=>(....)). Please see 'jessehouwing' reply.

The syntax .Where(function(f) ....) is a VB.Net equivalent of the lambda expression in C#. 
The lambda expression .Where(d => (...)) means 'd' goes to (some action or expression ). 
Let me know if this helps.